# FFT - Filtering - Inverse FFT - Offset remaining

Tags: python, fft, offset

I'm doing the following: Perform a FFT / Cut every frequency above 100Hz in the FFT results / Perform an Inverse-FFT

It works well... if the original dataset doesn't have an offset ! If it has an offset, the output result magnitude is corrupted.

Examples:

[Without offset](http://i62.tinypic.com/29mt7qw.png)

[With offset (and noise)](http://fr.tinypic.com/r/15pfqq0/8)

I'm not even sure that I can do what I'm doing, mathematically speaking.  All I can observe is that with offset, the fundamental frequency is twice the original one ???!!!

**Do you have an idea why the offset is altered ?**

The code:

```
def FFT(data,time_step):
    """ 
    Perform FFT on raw data and return result of FFT (yf) and frequency axis (xf).

    """
    """
    #Test code for the manual frequency magnitude plot
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    #Generate sinus waves
    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50000)   #You need enough points to be able to capture information (Shannon theorem)
    data = np.sin(x*2*np.pi*50) + 0.5*np.sin(x*2*np.pi*200)

    time_step = (x[-1]-x[0])/x.size

    list_data = FFT(data,time_step)

    x = list_data[0]
    y = list_data[1]    

    plt.figure()
    plt.xlim(0,300)
    plt.plot(x,np.abs(y)/max(np.abs(y)),'k-+')

    """    

    N_points = data.size    

    #FFT
    yf_original=np.fft.fft(data*time_step) #*dt really necessary? Better for units, probably

    #Post-pro
    #We keep only the positive part
    yf=yf_original[0:N_points/2]

    #fundamental frequency
    f1=1/(N_points*time_step)

    #Generate the frequency axis - n*f1
    xf=np.linspace(0,N_points/2*f1,N_points/2)


    return [xf, yf, yf_original]



def Inverse_FFT(data,time_step,freq_cut):

    list_data = FFT(data,time_step)

    N_points = data.size    

    #FFT data
    x = list_data[0]
    yf_full = list_data[2]

    #Look where the frequency is above freq_cut
    index = np.where(x > freq_cut)
    x_new_halfpos = x[0:index[0][0]-1]  #Contains N_points/2

    yf_new = np.concatenate((yf_full[0:index[0][0]-1], yf_full[N_points/2 +1:index[0][0]-1])) 

    #Apply inverse-fft
    y_complex = np.fft.ifft(yf_new)

    #Calculate new time_step ??!!
    N_points_new = x_new_halfpos.size *2
    f1 = x_new_halfpos[1]
    time_step_new = 1/(N_points_new*f1)

    #Create back the x-axis for plotting. The original data were distributed every time_step. Now, it is every time_step_new
    """ WARNING - It assumes that the new x_new axis is equally distributed - True ?!? """
    x_new = np.linspace(0,N_points_new*time_step_new,N_points_new/2)


    y_new = y_complex.real  / time_step_new

    return [x_new,y_new]
```

Example code of the generated examples:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Generate sinus waves
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50000)   #You need enough points to be able to capture information (Shannon theorem)
data = np.sin(x*2*np.pi*5) + 0.5*np.sin(x*2*np.pi*20) + 0.2*np.random.normal(x)

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,np.pi/4)
plt.plot(x,data)

time_step = (x[-1]-x[0])/x.size

list_data = FFT(data,time_step)

x = list_data[0]
y = list_data[1]    

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,30)
plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude")
plt.plot(x,np.abs(y)/max(np.abs(y)),'k-+')

#Anti-FFT
data_new = Inverse_FFT(data,time_step,100)

x_new = data_new[0]
y_new = data_new[1]
time_step_new = (x_new[-1]-x_new[0])/x_new.size

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,np.pi/4)
plt.plot(x_new,y_new)

list_data_new = FFT(y_new,time_step_new)

x_newfft = list_data_new[0]
y_newfft = list_data_new[1]    

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0,30)
plt.xlabel("Frequency [Hz]")
plt.ylabel("Normalized magnitude")
plt.plot(x_newfft,np.abs(y_newfft)/max(np.abs(y_newfft)),'k-+')
```

Thank you !

Kind Regards,

EDIT:
Corrected function:

```
def Anti_FFT(data,time_step,freq_cut):

    list_data = FFT(data,time_step)

    N_points = data.size    

    #FFT data
    x = list_data[0]
    yf_full = list_data[2]

    #Look where the frequency is above freq_cut
    index = np.where(x > freq_cut)
    x_new_halfpos = x[0:index[0][0]-1]  #Contains N_points/2

    #Fill with zeros
    yf_new = yf_full
    yf_new[index[0][0]:N_points/2 +1]=0
    yf_new[N_points/2 +1 :-index[0][0]]=0 #The negative part is symmetric. The last term is the 1st term of the positive part

    #Apply anti-fft
    y_complex = np.fft.ifft(yf_new)

    #Calculate the """new""" x_axis
    x_new = np.linspace(0,N_points*time_step,N_points)

    #Divide by the time_step to get the right units
    y_new = y_complex.real / time_step

    return [x_new,y_new]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "offset"?

Comment: The mean value represented by the fundamental frequency.
Without noise: The mean is equal to 0 => No fundamental frequency => No offset
 // With noise: The mean is equal !=0 => Fundamental frequency exists => Offset //

An example on my real data, the blue curve: original / red curve: modified: http://fr.tinypic.com/r/5f2743/8

Comment: It looks like you are missing the zero insertion in `yf_new` between the two concatenated parts (to the same size as the original sequence). Don't have python on this system to validate a fix for this. By the way, since you are dealing with real data, it might be easier to use `rfft`.

Comment: Good point. It permits to be consistent and have the same number of point between the input/output.
I have replaced: `yf_new = np.concatenate((yf_full[0:index[0][0]-1], yf_full[N_points/2 +1:index[0][0]-1]))`  by     `#Fill with zeros
    yf_new = yf_full
    yf_new[index[0][0]:N_points/2 +1]=0
    yf_new[N_points/2 +1 + index[0][0]:]=0`
Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem of offset :/
Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the last part be something like `yf_new[N_points/2+1:-index[0][0]) = 0` considering that the upper half spectrum is a symmetry (ie. the samples you want to keep are in reverse order at the end of the array)?

Comment: Damn it ! I didn't know it was symmetric !
Problem solved, it works even with noise. And even with my data !
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

DFT(f), call it F, of a sequence f of N (even) real values has these properties:

F(0), (the DC offset), is a real number

F(N/2) is a real number, the amplitude of the Nyquist frequency.
For i in [1..N/2-1] it is the case that F[N/2+i]* = F[N/2-i], where '*' indicates complex conjugate.

Your manipulation of F must preserve those properties.

FYI, There are special routines for real valued input that use that symmetry to calculate FFT and iFFT almost twice as fast as their general counterparts for complex data.